# pagination 404 error, same slug home and categories

Tags: categories, pagination, 404-error, slug, homepage

I would like to change the permalink for categories. I configured thé prefix of categories with `actions`
I have a page for the home page wich have a slug `actions`
All the website worked correctly.
URL of home [www.mywebsite.com/actions](http://www.mywebsite.com/actions)
URL of the first category is

```
www.mywebsite.com/actions/first-slug
```

The pagination work for all categories :
URL is `www.mywebsite.com/actions/first-slug/page/2`

But the home page have a problem with the pagination
URL of page 2 with all posts is : `www.mywebsite.com/actions/page/2`
I have an error 404. It's normal because the category `page` not existe...

How to have the same slug for the home page and the slug of categories without an 404 error for the pagination to the home page?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It doesn't sound like it will work the way you set it up, because WordPress uses the slugs to determine what type of content to show. If you set your `/actions/` page as the Front Page in Settings > Reading, so that its URL is just at `http://example.com`, that should allow pagination to work on the homepage and on your posts.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, and if it was it might have SEO consequences, you have 2 sets of URL rewrite rules that map on to the same thing

Comment: However it seems consistent to have a clean URL with "blog / category"